# revoke google access and make the user sign in again

Tags: android, authentication, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-authentication

I am new to android and firebase. I am learning to use the user authentication feature of firebase with android. What I want to do is to make the user sign in again with their username and password after they have pressed the revoke button. I am using the code blocks from the sample java file of firebase. My problem is this - even after the user presses the revoke button, the choose account dialog box comes up and the user can simply select the account without even entering the username, forget the password.

```
 private FirebaseAuth mAuth; /*firebase authorization object*/
 private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
 private boolean isAccntConnected;
 .
 .
 . 
 revokeBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.revoke_google);
 mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
 .
 .
 GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

  mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
           //.enableAutoManage(this /*FragmentActivity*/, this/*OnConnectionFailedListener*/)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API,gso)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();
.
.
.
private void revokeAccess() {
    //First we sign out of Firebase
    mAuth.signOut();
    //Next we sign out of google
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        mGoogleApiClient.clearDefaultAccountAndReconnect();
        Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
                new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(Status status) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Sign Out using Google Api.");
                        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
                        //CALL TO DISCONNECT GoogleApiClient
                        isAccntConnected = false;
                    }
                });
    }
    //Next we revoke google access
    Auth.GoogleSignInApi.revokeAccess(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
            new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
                    //update the user interface by removing the revoke google button
                    findViewById(R.id.revoke_google).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
    );
.
.
.
 @Override
protected void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}
.
.
.

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle){
    this.isAccntConnected = true;
}
```

Comment: Trim down your code to the line in question, do not post your whole code. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) SO article and update your question accordingly.